# curl: (60) error on installation of GHCup for Haskell on Mac High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: haskell, ghcup

I am a beginner looking to learn basics of Haskell before my first term at university. I recently installed GHCup for Haskell (mac) using the terminal window command

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh
```

However, it gave me this error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
HTTPS-proxy has similar options --proxy-cacert and --proxy-insecure.
```

It shows that my SSL certificate has expired, is there a way I can fix this? My version is a mac High Sierra 10.13.6 and GHCup seems to be compatible with 10.13>, so I'm not really sure...

Comment: The error says "use the -k option". HAve you tried that?